# Gradle maven-publish - custom local maven repository location

Tags: maven, gradle

I am using:

```
apply plugin: "maven-publish"
```

I am trying to install my artifact in $buildDir/repo instead of ~/.m2/repository.

I have tried this:

```
publishing {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "$buildDir/repo"
    }
  }
}
```

and this:

```
-Dmvn.repo.local=build/repo
```

But those are ignored.

I would like to avoid using the settings.xml to set that, is it possible?